# Prove B is a closed subset of X given the f and g are continous?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Let $(X;\rho)$, $(Y;\sigma)$ be metric spaces. Let $f,g : X \to Y$ be continuous.

Prove that the set $B=\{x\in X: f(x)=g(x)\}$ is a closed subset of $X$

Comment: What are your thoughts? Do you know (or can you prove) that $\{x\mid f(x)=0\}$ is closed?

Comment: @HenningMakholm That would require $0\in Y$.

Comment: I do not know that the set is closed. I know that to prove it to be closed I would have to show that the set contains its limits points or that the complement of the set is open.

Comment: @Hagen: If $0\notin Y$, then we're looking at the empty set, which is most certainly closed. :-p

Comment: @HenningMakholm Nobody says that $Y$ carries an additive structure

Comment: @Hagen: Correct, _nobody_ says that, including me.

Comment: @Henning : Hahaha, that's one way to put it! But I don't think this very, very funny joke helps OP...

Answer (score 1):

Show that $B_{y,r}=\{\,x\in X\mid \sigma(f(x),y)<r\land \sigma(g(x),y)>r\,\}$ is open for all $y\in Y$, $r>0$. Then note that $$\bigcup_{y\in Y,r>0}B_{y,r}=Y\setminus B.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $x_n \rightarrow x$ then what happens to $f(x_n) $? $g(x_n) $?

Comment: Ahhhh sequences. Love 'em! This answer is my favorite.

Answer (score 1):

Since $Y$ is Hausdorff (being a metric space), $\Delta = \{(y, y) : y \in Y\}$ is closed in $Y \times Y$ (why?). Hence $B = (f \times g)^{-1}(\Delta)$ is also closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have shown that the metric $\sigma : Y \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then the function $h : X \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $h(x) = \sigma(f(x),g(x))$ is the composition of continuous functions and is therefore continuous itself. Now, $\{0\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so $h^{-1}(\{0\})$ will have to be a closed subset of $X$ since $h$ is continuous.